# Remove call() when using Mock

Tags: python, mocking

In python 2.6 or 2.7, I want to get rid of the 'call' stuff when using Mock.call_args_list.

I basically want to check if the mock is well called when some argument.

I have something like:

```
a = Mock()
...
self.assertEqual(a.call_args_list, ...)
```

but the call_args_list looks like:

```
[call(arg1, arg2, arg3), call(...)]
```

How can I access to the arg2 value precisely without recreating a complete call object?

if there a way to iterate in all the "call" object and get a list of all argument and just extract whatever I need?

The thing is that previously I had no problem, the call_args_list returned me lists without this "call" stuff and I was able to do what I wanted to do, but for some reason the "call" started appearing and I don't know how to handle it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> import mock
>>> my_call = mock.call('test', example=3)
>>> name, args, kwargs = my_call
>>> name
''
>>> args
('test',)
>>> kwargs
{'example': 3}
```

This will give you the name (not always available), the positional arguments and the keyword arguments of the call. According to [the documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#calls-as-tuples), the `call()` objects in `call_args_list` are actually tuples with two values, not three. So you can do:

```
>>> args, kwargs = my_call
```

You can also use indexing the get the values. For example, `my_call[2]` will give you the keyword arguments. This can be used to convert `call_args_list` into the arguments:

```
>>> call1 = mock.call('test', example=3)
>>> call2 = mock.call('test', example=4, value=5)
>>> call_args_list = [call1, call2]
>>> [(item[1], item[2]) for item in call_args_list]
[(('test',), {'example': 3}), (('test',), {'example': 4, 'value': 5})]
```

Comment: thanks for this answer.

For call_args_list, [0] is arg list and [1] seems to be the kwargs.

Comment: Universal variant for both 2-item and 3-item tuples:
`args, kwargs = a.call_args[:-2]` - here we always take last 2 items.